# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unable to find element in cloned iframe

Tags: javascript, html2canvas, angular10

I am trying to convert a simple html to canvas in angular. But facing "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unable to find element in cloned iframe" this issue.
I am using angular 10

```
var body = document.createElement('div');
  body.id = 'abc';
  body.innerHTML = 'Hello';
  html2canvas(body).then(canvas => {
    console.log(canvas);
  }).then(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```